# how do i create a new CardView?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

i am trying to add a new card view/new card thingy(sorry i'm new) to my app. right now, it all works fine, but how would i add more? i would also like to know how to do it on FAB click. Here is my code

```
public class WeatherListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WeatherListAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private List<WeatherData> weatherDataList;

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //?
        View view1 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_weather_card,parent,false);
        View view2 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_weather_card,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        WeatherData weatherData = this.weatherDataList.get(position);
        holder.locationTextView.setText(weatherData.getName());
        holder.tempTextView.setText("Temperature: "+weatherData.getWeatherDetails().getTemperature());
        holder.humidTextView.setText("Humidity: "+ weatherData.getWeatherDetails().getHumidity());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.weatherDataList.size();
    }

    protected static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView locationTextView;
        public TextView tempTextView;
        public TextView humidTextView;
        public ViewHolder(View v){
            super(v);
            locationTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.locationTextView);
            tempTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tempTextView);
            humidTextView= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.humidText);
        }




    }

    public WeatherListAdapter(List<WeatherData> weatherDataList){
        this.weatherDataList = weatherDataList;

    }
}
```

if i need to add more to help you figure it out, just leave a comment. Thanks!
**WeatherListActivity-**

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<WeatherData> mWeatherDataList;
WeatherListAdapter mAdpapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_weather_list);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mWeatherDataList = new ArrayList<WeatherData>();








    final WeatherApiManager weatherApiManager = new WeatherApiManager();
    weatherApiManager.getWeatherByCoordinate(35.744644099999995, -78.86395929999999, new WeatherCallback() {
        @Override
        public void weatherDownloadCompleted(boolean success, WeatherData weatherData) {
            List<WeatherData> weatherDataList = new ArrayList<WeatherData>();
           // weatherDataList.add(weatherData);
          //  weatherDataList.add(weatherData);

            mAdpapter = new WeatherListAdapter(weatherDataList);






            //why does this have to be in here?
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdpapter);

        }
    });



    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            final WeatherApiManager weatherApiManager = new WeatherApiManager();
            weatherApiManager.getWeatherByCoordinate(35.744644099999995, -78.86395929999999, new WeatherCallback() {
                @Override
                public void weatherDownloadCompleted(boolean success, WeatherData weatherData) {
                    List<WeatherData> weatherDataList = new ArrayList<WeatherData>();

                    weatherDataList.add(weatherData);

                    mAdpapter = new WeatherListAdapter(weatherDataList);


                    //why does this have to be in here?
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdpapter);


                }
            });

            updateUI();


        }
    });


}
```

Comment: Are you trying to add just one card or a dynamic number or cards?

Comment: 1 at a time, but i would like it if the user could add it with a FAB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use CardView in your RecyclerView (and then attach the TextViews you had previously) I would do something like this:

```
public class WeatherListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WeatherListAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private List<WeatherData> weatherDataList;

    public TextView locationTextView;
    public TextView tempTextView;
    public TextView humidTextView;

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // Here we are inflating the CardView
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_weather_card, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        WeatherData weatherData = this.weatherDataList.get(position);
        CardView cardView = holder.cardView;

        // We then add these items to each CardView
        locationTextView = (TextView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.locationTextView);
        tempTextView = (TextView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.tempTextView);
        humidTextView= (TextView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.humidText);

        locationTextView.setText(weatherData.getName());
        tempTextView.setText("Temperature: "+weatherData.getWeatherDetails().getTemperature());
        humidTextView.setText("Humidity: "+ weatherData.getWeatherDetails().getHumidity());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.weatherDataList.size();
    }

    protected static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public CardView cardView;

        public ViewHolder(View v){
            super(v);
            // Each ViewHolder only has a CardView (even though that CardView has child TextViews
            cardView = (CardView) v;
        }

    }

    public WeatherListAdapter(List<WeatherData> weatherDataList){
        this.weatherDataList = weatherDataList;
    }
}
```

Then you just have to make sure that the `adapter_weather_card.xml` in your layouts has the `<TextView>` items for `locationTextView`, `tempTextView` and `humidTextView` so they can all be displayed on each CardView.

**Sample Activity Using This WeatherListAdapter**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    WeatherListAdapter mAdapter;
    List<WeatherData> mList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mList = new ArrayList<>();
        // Just a bunch of sample data we're using to populate the RecyclerView
        mList.add(new WeatherData("Sacramento", "88", "60"));
        mList.add(new WeatherData("Dallas", "96", "40"));
        mList.add(new WeatherData("Orlando", "80", "85"));
        mList.add(new WeatherData("Seattle", "68", "78"));

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        // In your WeatherListAdapater class you pass a List to the constructor, this is the
        // list that contains all the WeatherData and the list we use to add new CardViews.
        mAdapter = new WeatherListAdapter(mList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Adding a new item to our WeatherData list with the FAB
                // This item will become a new CardView
                // We can similarly remove CardViews by calling remove()
                mList.add(new WeatherData("Boston", "67", "50"));
                // Updating the UI after adding the CardView so it shows up
                updateUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        // The list we passed to the mAdapter was changed so we have to notify it in order to update
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

**Sample XML For This Activity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Sample CardView XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/locationTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tempTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/humidText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: thanks, but i got an error. I am sorry if i didn't make myself clear enough, but i want to add multiple cards(idk if that is the right name, but it looks like it) below one another, and eventally on an FAB click. do you know how i would do this? thanks.

Comment: What error did you get? And are you trying to make a RecyclerView with several CardViews?

Comment: it could not resolve the text views. and yes i think that is what i am trying to do.

Comment: Okay, I just edited the code in my post so that it should run (at least it worked when I tested it). Let me know if it's still giving you errors.

Comment: Ok, I will try it out when I get a chance. Will this allow me to have multiple cards?

Comment: Yup, I tested it using about five or so. You just have to add them to the list that gets passed to the Adapter. And, in case you don't already know, don't forget to call `notifyDataSetChanged();` on your Adapter when you add a card so it refreshes the RecyclerView.

Comment: sorry, but I am not sure I understand this. what list would I add the cardviews to? and when would I put the notifyDataSetChanged()? thanks.

Comment: I just updated the post with an example activity and the XML data I used to test it. I included some comments to help explain what each part is doing. You also mentioned wanting to add to the list with a FAB so I included that in the sample too.

Comment: Thank you. i got a second card up finally but still can not seem to figure out why the fab wont work. i know why it isn't working, i just dont know how to fix it. i have updated my code to show you.

Comment: If you want your `updateUI()` to refresh your RecyclerView then you need to make sure your `recyclerView` variable is always passed `mAdapter` because that is the Adapter we update in `updateUI()`. In a few places you're creating a new anonymous Adapter via `new WeatherListAdapter(...)` which won't update because we're updating `mAdapter` and it's no longer associated with the `recyclerView`.

Comment: first off, thank you for your help, but i am still kind of confused on how i would make it work. is their any way to get the weatherDataList from  the weatherDownloadCompleted() method? or how would i do it with the mAdapter? EDIT: i am now able to make one appear on click but after that it doesnt work. i have updated my code.

Comment: Also, how would i add padding/space in between the two cards? Thanks.

Comment: Adding `android:layout_margin="10dp"` in your CardView XML will produce a padding. Also, can you explain what you want your app to do? What should happen when the user presses the FAB? Do you want the old cards to stay in the RecyclerView?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110945/discussion-between-jack-arnold-and-apicellaj).

Answer (score 0):

A simple Card View can be added using the `CardView` widget in your XML layout file. This is an example of an implementation:

```
<!-- Root element of the XML Layout file -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ... >

    <!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <!-- Here goes the content of the card -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

You also have to download the Android Support Libraries using the SDK Manager if you don't have them already  (you can find them in the 'Extras' directory at the bottom of the list of downloadable content) and then add the dependency in your Gradle configuration:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
}
```

Source: [Android Developers website](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#CardView)